# Circuit to sample engine RPM

Tags: voltage, transistors

I have been working on a circuit to sample a single cylinder engine RPM.  It works accurately, but I wonder if there could be possible damage to MCU due to high voltages from the ignition coil.

From research I have established that the coil produces between 300 - 450 V pulsed DC which is only present less than 1 ms every rotation.

[image: IGNITION RPM CIRCUIT]

From the picture, the ignition is sampled through a diode and a 510K resistor.  This brings the power below 500mW below the maximum power of the 3906 transistor.  Should the high voltage be taken into account and use a 450V base/emitter transistor?

The low voltage of the ignition is sourced from the 'PRIMARY' side of the ignition coil (where the kill switch is located.)  As mentioned, the circuit seems to work without issue so could any change be made to make it more robust?

Comment: Where did you get the transistor circuit from? Are you aware that it uses collector and emitter in reversed operation?

Comment: yes I asked and electronics guy at work some time ago and he suggested this circuit - although it was not a circuit he would implement

Comment: But, why is it done this way? I see no reason for this configuration.

Comment: I'Ve no idea this iss why i ask here, notheless it works?  Is there a better solution?

Comment: Am I to assume there is no "electronic ignition"?

Comment: Magneto or battery powered ignition?

Comment: Its a magneto ignition

Answer (score 0):

try using a HAL sensor, it's a tiny SMD chip that reacts on magnets, like little neodymium.
Modify the crank pulley to pres fit a neodymium magnet and place the HAL sensor on top.

That's how other people do it and sell advanced spark distributors without mechanical elements.

It's how BMW does in in the R1100 motorcycles and many other aswel

[image]
https://www.euromotoelectrics.com/BOSCH-Hall-Effect-Sensor-R1100-p/boignsen-r137.htm
BMW R1100.. Hall sensor.

Electronic Distributor Lucas 45D 4 cyl Ford
[image]
https://www.classiccaraccessories.co.nz/products/electronic-distributor-lucas-45d4-ford

Comment: single cylinder engines don't have distributors.

Comment: @Jasen but they use some sort of switch to ignite fuel.

Comment: @NaturalDemon  That was my option in the first place but when i realised i could sample the primary with a transistor i tried this route, also the same circuit (with the adition of an extra transistor) can be used as a kill switch

Comment: @Andy Maybe better to use software, like Microchip Fubarino (32bit Arduino IDE compatible, on a very small pcb and cheaper), you can calculate down to a floating point precision number, using either a millisecond timer or a Mega Hertz timer and add other software stuff to it.

Comment: @Andy a SSD1306 128 x 32 px OLED display is less than 5us$, easy to attach and drive, they look pretty cool too in dark situations, either white or blue.
Just need to download the Adafruit or other library.

Comment: @Andy, once you master the software (of counting exactly the RPM), you could use a transistor connected to the coil, to advance or retard the ignition for max power, like it's done in old cars with a vacuum hose. they used a 4mHz Intel mcu's back than on the first cars with injection. the 48 mHz of the microchip Fubarino should be more than sufficient.

You setup a timer using a "interrupt" routine/function, choose either millisecond, microsecond or nanosecond timer and count the pulses from your hardware during a second. some easy math gives the exact rpm.

Answer (score 0):

The PNP triggers when it sees current being pulled down through its base, from the coil primary negative voltage spike as the points open.

Now, how is that possible since the diode is wired in reverse? It should block the base current, right?

Three possible explanations:

- reverse-bias diode operating as a capacitor (about 8 pF, so likely)
- coil spike is exceeding the diode reverse breakdown (1000V, so less likely)
- reverse leakage current (maybe)

The design would probably still work if you used a small, high voltage rated capacitor instead of the diode. But there’s no reason to change it, seems reasonable if not clever.

Your pickup wire could become a few turns twisted around the coil primary - that is, AC couple it. Then you could get rid of the diode.

Comment: thank you, i tried the coil around the HT lead but was getting spurious results from 4 to 22 turns just too much noise pick up, you could see the firing but was picking up noise all over the place, oddly with less turns.

Comment: So do you think the 3906 transistor will suffice?

Comment: I have some concern about the base-emitter reverse voltage. Assuming 8pF across the diode, I did a simulation and it's seeing the peak positive primary voltage (about 120V in my sim), which is more than a BJT can live with. The diode capacitance does decrease with reverse bias, but I'd need to model it in real Spice to see it. In short this circuit relies on some parasitic behavior to make it work; I don't have confidence in its reliability. I think the BJT will eventually fail.